# how does to install proper way to npm in windows?

Tags: angularjs

some day before i have start to learn angular js 2 and read tutorial to install npm in windows but nothing meaning full found from it I am new to programming and want to learn to angular js. anybody help me thanks

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is install cgywin or other shell (by example Git shell)
After that you should go to [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) site and install it,
After the installation restart your computer and in the prompt of the shell you installed before write `npm -v` this should show the version of npm you have already installed.

(It has take about 15 sec to find the solution in google...) [reference link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows)
Next time is better if you research yourself a little bit more.

Best Regards

Comment: when you install npm how to set with github path and more? i have already read this post.